# How to send large strings from Android to server (PHP)?

Tags: php, android

I use the below code. I am only able to see some part of string which I send in my database.

```
         List<NameValuePair> elements = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);


            elements.add((new BasicNameValuePair("phone",question)));
            elements.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",answer));
            elements.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date",date));

            try{

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);


                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(elements));

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Comment: when i directly added to my db it works the prob is with the string i send from Android

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
List<NameValuePair> elements = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
```

with

```
List<NameValuePair> elements = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
```

after this you can insert 'n' number of string in list.

Comment: No , its not the prob  the prob is with the length of string my string is of 2000 char and i need to send it to the server .

Comment: wat abt gzip compression android ?

Comment: I dont think that creates problem, i used to send 4000-5000 char string with using namevalupair list.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to check length defined for fields in database engine. Secondly as you are posting data to URL it supports much lengthy data. There would be some special character in your input which will be making problem.

Also provide server side code and if not possible share input you given and one stored in DB.

For debugging purpose you can run query directly on DB and check if the input you are trying to save is inserted or not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: when i directly added to my db it works the prob is with the string i send from Android